# Uncaught Promise Error: TypeError: member is not a function

Tags: javascript, node.js, typeerror, discord.js

With my verification bot, it DMs the user, the user responds with a code, and it's supposed to give a role. However, it does nothing and posts this error.

> Uncaught Promise Error:
>   TypeError: `member` is not a function

I've tried changing `users` to `members` and vice versa, defining the guild, role, etc. in the config instead, but none of it has resolved the error.

```js
client.on('message', async (message) => {
    if (message.author.bot || !message.author.token || message.channel.type !== `dm`) return
    if (message.content !== (verifymsg.replace('{token}', message.author.token))) return
    message.channel.send({
        embed: {
            color: Math.floor(Math.random() * (0xFFFFFF + 1)),
            description: completemsg,
            footer: {
                text: `Verification Success`
            }
        }
    })
  let member = message.mentions.users.first(); 
    member(message.member).addRole(member.guild("528721525390442526").roles.find("name", "Member"));
})
```

I expect a role to be added to the member, giving them access to the guild.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way you've written `member(message.member)` is telling JavaScript to execute the function `member()` with a parameter `message.member`. You haven't defined the said function anywhere within your code, so that's why it's throwing the error.

You want to use the [`Guild.member()`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Guild?scrollTo=member) *method*.

Example:

```js
try {
  const guild = client.guilds.get('528721525390442526');
  const member = guild.member(message.author.id);
  const role = guild.roles.find(r => r.name === 'Member');

  member.addRole(role);
  member.send('Verification successful.');
} catch(err) {
  console.error(err);
}
```

Comment: Cheers, Along with that I've tried changing "message.mentions.members.first();" to "message.mentions.users.first();" because i'm always getting "TypeError: Cannot read property 'first' of null" whenever i use members.first

Comment: Sounds like the command author isn't mentioning anyone. I edited the code to check that there are mentioned members first.

Comment: It's going up to where it responds "Verified" and yet it still doesn't add the role, I've tried "  member.addRole("name", "Member");" but nope.

Comment: I've edited the code again to show the role adding in further detail.

Comment: Really isn't liking me today, "ReferenceError: member is not defined". "  if (!message.mentions.members) return message.channel.send(member.toString() + "Thank you for verifying.");" Wasn't tagging them and i think that is why it wasn't giving them said role.

Comment: `member` isn't defined yet for it to be used in that line. If there aren't any mentioned members, it can't be either. Who are you trying to tag?

Comment: Moved member up higher, before the "try" Will update.
Nope, "Cannot read property first of null"
So, Trying to mention the person who responds (the other person in that DM). It DM's the person, the person responds w/ code and then it should add a role to the person in the guild. (Hence why in my original code i defined the guild by ID)

Comment: If no members are mentioned, it's going to throw your previous error again. That was the point of checking if members were mentioned.

Comment: So, really what i want to do is mention the person the bot is DMing (after the person sends the code) so the bot can add a role (in the defined guild) to the person it mentioned. Not really sure how to do that though.

Comment: My apologies, I misunderstood the intentions of your code. See the edited version.

Comment: Thanks, Works now :D I'm still relatively new to node and javascript as a whole, will be studying more to use methods like the one you posted above ^

Comment: Glad I could help. If this answer resolves your issues, feel free to accept it with the green checkmark next to it.